# How can I plot polar coordinates in SAGE?

Tags: plot, sage

I want to plot a point in the polar coordinate system using SAGE. For instance the given is cis 135°. Can somebody tell me what are the commands for this to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that the polar plotting facility and point plotting don't play well (though there is a `polar_plot` command if you have a function to plot).  [This seems to work](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLzEvPSVWwVTA0NuXlKikqTY1PRIjoaxhpFWRq8nIV5GfmlWhEJ-cXayDUaOoUZ-Yh82N1kvNz8ots1YtSU9Q1AfZPHSo=&lang=sage) but you might not like it so much; I would recommend turning this into a function if you have a lot to plot.

```
angle = 135
true_angle = 135/180*pi
point([cos(true_angle),sin(true_angle)],color='red')
```

Comment: Yes, this graph is not what I was expecting. The line of code, to the best of my knowledge, for cis 135° should be point([cos(3*pi/4),sin(3*pi/4)], color='red'). Theta should be 45° of Quadrant II. But anyways this led me into having a polar graph for the trigonometric form of a complex number so I will accept your answer.

Comment: You're right, I think I got overzealous with my `pi`s!  I'll edit now.